# Help Needed to create PNFT list/sell instruction through Metaplex AuctionHouse

Tags: metaplex, nft, auction-house

For Non pnft list transactions, I am using the below accounts

```
export declare type SellInstructionAccounts = {
    wallet: web3.PublicKey;
    tokenAccount: web3.PublicKey;
    metadata: web3.PublicKey;
    authority: web3.PublicKey;
    auctionHouse: web3.PublicKey;
    auctionHouseFeeAccount: web3.PublicKey;
    sellerTradeState: web3.PublicKey;
    freeSellerTradeState: web3.PublicKey;
    tokenProgram?: web3.PublicKey;
    systemProgram?: web3.PublicKey;
    programAsSigner: web3.PublicKey;
    rent?: web3.PublicKey;
    anchorRemainingAccounts?: web3.AccountMeta[];
};
```

when I try to list a pnft, I am getting "Account Frozen", it is because for pnft the underlying token account is frozen all the time. Do I need to pass any new accounts in the transaction to list a PNFT through auction-house, it would be super helpful if someone can provide sample snippet or sample auction-house pnft transaction signature.

Comment: Hi @Kiran - Have you resolved the issue from the PNFT side, or are you still facing the same problem?

Comment: The issue is resolved.

Comment: That's great - could you please clarify can we use the same metaplex auction house function that we used on simple nft. like listing selling etc

Comment: Yes we can use the same, but for PNFTS you need to add remaining_accounts for sell, execute_sale. Also for the execute_sale the auction_house authority or seller must sign

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Kiran could you please help me to figure out this? remaining accounts mean. I was listing the my nft using like this
    const list = await metaplex.auctionHouse().list({
      auctionHouse: auctionHouseAccount,
      mintAccount: nft_address,
      price: amount,
    });
    console.log("list", list); 

on this show Account frozen error

Comment: Hi @kiran- 
I have been stuck in this problem for the past 15 days. I posted a question but haven't received any answers. Could you please help me with this matter?


https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/program-log-error-account-is-frozen

Comment: Hi @UmaidKhalid, see https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/auction-house/js/src/generated/instructions/sellRemainingAccounts.ts, this is for list instruction, for execute_sale also there will executeSaleRemainingAccounts you need to derive and pass these accounts with the usual sell, executeSale accounts. Last time I checked metaplex sdk is not updated for pnfts, so it is not possible to derive remaining accounts using sdk, derive the remaining accounts required for sell, execute_sale instruction and pass them in anchorRemainingAccounts for the instruction

Comment: @UmaidKhalid here is working my rust code I wrote way back to test pnft sell, buy, execute_sale, https://codeshare.io/j0qdbD. the link will expire in 24hrs

Comment: @UmaidKhalid, here is a reference to metaplex discord: https://discord.com/channels/848060988636921856/1137681223188234252

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Kiran for sharing the code and clearing up my doubts. I'll check this, and hopefully, it will work to run the auction.

Comment: Yes, I checked the Metaplex GitHub repository, but I couldn't find anything related to PNFTs. That's wy I faced issues regarding this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP resolved it without self-answering the question with the steps to resolve the issue. If you believe the solution to be of general use to the community, self-answer your question and accept your own answer now