# Program log: Error: Account is frozen

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, auction-house

I previously used a simple NFT on the Metaplex auction house to list, sell, and execute sales. However, now when I try to list my programmable NFT (PNFT), it shows an error: "**Program log: Error: Account is frozen.**" Could someone please clarify how to set up an auction house with programmable NFTs? Do I need to send a ruleset along with the listing, or are there any other options I should consider?
this is how I list the nft

```
const list = await metaplex.auctionHouse().list({
      auctionHouse: auction_house_obj,
      mintAccount: nft_address,
      price: amount,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For pNFTs I think you should try to unlock if first before using it on Auction House.

Comment: How can I unlock my PNFT and utilize it for an auction house or other purposes? Could you provide a link or snippet of information for this process?